# Why getting active record error when trying to work on arrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord, unique-constraint

I have the following association in my User model:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :friends, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'friend_id'
```

I have the following uniqueness constraint in my user_users table:

```
UNIQUE KEY `no_duplicate_friends` (`user_id`,`friend_id`)
```

In my code, I am retrieving a user's friends --> friends = user.friends. friends is an array.

I have a scenario where I want add the user with all those friends to the friends array.  Ex:

```
friends << user
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Duplicate entry '18-18' for key 'no_duplicate_friends': INSERT INTO `users_users` (`friend_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (18, 18)
```

What gives?

Comment: `friends` is the `user.friends`. ok. so you're trying to add the `user` as his own `friend`?

Comment: Yes. I'd want an exception to be thrown if I were trying to save to the DB.  However, I just want to add the user himself to his array of friends as part of some business logic that I want to pass to a controller.  Not saving to the database.

Comment: The error is thrown when I do friends << user. That is, when I try to add user to the array.  I never save it to the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you are trying to add `user`as a friend of `user`, ie, you have `user.id` in `user_with_all_those_homies`.

I believe something like the following may solve your problem:

```
# assuming user_with_all_those_homies is an array of users
user_with_all_those_homies.reject{ |u| u.id == user.id }
```

**Edit**

Ok, now i understood :]

Before saving to the database, remove the `user` from `friends` array:

```
friends.reject{ |f| f.id == user.id }
```

Comment: user_with_all_those_homies is not an array.